# Dynamic routing in angular2

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, angular-routing

I am trying to create dynamic routes with the index names I have in my elastic index. I was able to create dynamic routing by adding manually some names but when I try to insert the routes with my elastic index names it skips that part,

app.routing.ts

```
constructor(http: Http, router: Router) {
        http.get('http://localhost:9200/_stats').subscribe(data => {

            for (let entry of Object.keys(data.json().indices)) {
                router.config.push({path: entry, component: SearchComponent});
            }

        });
        router.config.push({path: 'test', component: SearchComponent});
        console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 1));
    }
```

I printed out my routes got results as below,

```
Routes:  [
 {
  "path": "home"
 },
 {
  "path": "404/pagenotfound"
 },
 {
  "path": "test"
 }
]
```

I couldn't find out why this code snippet skips the part where I insert my elastic index names. But when I printed out as below it shows the index names I trying to add is added.

```
http.get('http://localhost:9200/_stats').subscribe(data => {

            for (let entry of Object.keys(data.json().indices)) {
                router.config.push({path: entry, component: SearchComponent});
            }

            console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 1));
        });
```

Results I got when I print as above.

```
Routes:  [
 {
  "path": "home"
 },
 {
  "path": "404/pagenotfound"
 },
 {
  "path": "test"
 },
 {
  "path": "pokemon"
 },
 {
  "path": "cars"
 },
 {
  "path": "tweets"
 },
 {
  "path": "bikes"
 },
 {
  "path": "apple"
 }
]
```

When I tried to access the URL it throws an error as below.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tweets'
```

Could you please describe to me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
import {APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule,} from '@angular/common';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Routes, RouterModule, Router, Resolve} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from "./notfoundcomponent/notfoundcomponent.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {init} from "protractor/built/launcher";


export function loadRoutes(http: Http, router: Router) {
    return () => {
        router.resetConfig([
            {path: 'fd', component: HomeComponent}
        ]);
    };
}

let routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '404/pagenotfound', component: NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    providers: [{
        'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
        'useFactory': init,
        'deps': [Http, Router],
        'multi': true
    }],
    entryComponents: [SearchComponent]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {

        http.get('http://localhost:9200/_stats').subscribe(data => {

            for (let entry of Object.keys(data.json().indices)) {
                router.config.push({path: entry, component: SearchComponent});
            }
            console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 1));
        });

        console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need to use [resetConfig](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig)

```
router.resetConfig([
 { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
   { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
   { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
 ]}
]);
```

Other thing which i think should help is [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)

```
Add to providers 

 {
      'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
      'useFactory': loadRoutes,
      'deps': [Http, Router],
      'multi': true
    },
```

Then add loader

```
export function loadRoutes(http: Http, router: Router) {
   return () => {
  //DO your job here 
  };
```

}

As a result it will wait to load routes and only after that it will continue

Comment: nop, it's not working its reset the routes. but throws the same error as ```ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tweets'```

Comment: I did as you said and its failing to build now, This how my app.routing class looks like now. 
```@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    providers: [{
        'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
        'useFactory': init,
        'deps': [Http, Router],
        'multi': true
    }],
    entryComponents: [SearchComponent]
})```

Comment: @M.Ramzan Update your question with error you are getting otherwise i can't help.

Comment: I have added code in my question and the error says,
```C:\test\web\src\child_process doesn't exist```

Comment: @M.Ramzan my bad  usefactory should be  'useFactory': loadRoutes, and not init

Comment: Also clean your constructor inside of AppRoutingModule

Comment: Now its showing this error, ```Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
    at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer```